# how to create a textfile in a given path if the file doesn't exist

Tags: c, file-io

```
void my_create(char* path)
{
    FILE* fp;
    fp = fopen(path, "rb+");
    if (fp == NULL) /* File doesn't exist*/ 
        fp = fopen(path, "wb");
}
```

Why doesn't it work ? or am I doing something wrong by given wrong path ?
Not so sure.

Thanks in advance

Comment: fp = fopen(path, "w+"); gives you to create an empty file for both reading and writing.

Comment: @tigris

So should I use w+ instead of wb and my code will work ?

Comment: how is the function called?

Comment: my_create("/home/bob/hello.txt");

Comment: Try calling `perror` or printing the value of `strerror(errno)` after the failure.  It may be that a permissions problem on `/home/bob/` is causing problems, or it may be that `/home/bob/` does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

File name may be unacceptable or you live a permission problem.

Try this :

```
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

void my_create(char* path)
{
    FILE* fp;
    fp = fopen(path, "rb+");
    if (fp == NULL) { /* File doesn't exist*/ 
        printf ("File does not exist : %s", path)
        fp = fopen(path, "wb+");
        if (fp == NULL) {
            fprintf (stderr, "Cannot create file : %s\n", path);
            fprintf (stderr, "Reason : %s" , strerror (errno));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Suggest using `perror` or `strerror` to help diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think checking file exists or not with fopen is the correct way.
You can use stat().

```
struct stat st = {0};
if (stat(path, &st) == -1) 
{
    FILE *fp = fopen(path, "w+");
    if (!fp) printf("Can not create file: %d\n", errno);
    else fclose(fp); 
}
```